# Input a text file in a two dimensional array with doubles

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new in Java.
I want to input a text file and create from it a two dimensional array the input is
like this

```
12,242 323,2324
23,4434 23,4534
23,434 56,3434
....
34,434 43,3443
```

I have tried

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class InputText {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int i=0; 
    File file;
    file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner read=new Scanner(file);

    while (read.hasNextLine()) {
      String line=read.nextLine();
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

which gives me the input but I cannot insert this in an array I tried different ways like splitting it.

Any suggestions?
Sorry for not being clear. The input i mentioned is doubles seperated by spaces. Also the format i gave you is what i get after i run the part of the programm i wrote. What i see in the text file is the numbers seperated by spaces. I tried to implement your suggestion but nothing seemed to work. I'm really lost here....

Comment: `I tried different ways like splitting it` and what was the result of these tries?

Comment: Array of which type you need?

Comment: Btw: `12,242` this needs a correct `Locale` setting to allow the comma as the separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split a line to two numbers you can use

```
string[] numbers = line.split("\\s+");
```

If you want to read a double with comma

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
...
double d1 =  format.parse(numbers[0]).doubleValue();
double d2 =  format.parse(numbers[1]).doubleValue();
```

Personally i prefer to use scanner. In that case create it with

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine()).useLocale(Locale.FRANCE);
  if (!scanner2.hasNextDouble()){ 
    System.out.println("Do not have a pair");
    continue;
  }
  double d1 = scanner2.nextDouble();
  if (!scanner2.hasNextDouble()){ 
    System.out.println("Do not have a pair");
    continue;
  }
  double d2 = scanner2.nextDouble();
  //do something
}
```

Comment: @Tom Yes, but that approach is not very clean. If it is not a single whitespace then code would brake (ex: double space, other whitespace, tab, ...)

Comment: Well, then split with `\\s+` so the amount of whitespaces doesn't matter if there is at least one.

Comment: @Tom "\\s+" is better then " ", but you still need to check at least **if(numbers.length!=2){...};** in order to detect if both numbers exist. Anyways +1 for comment.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the line.. you will have to again split the string on ','. The split string need to be converted into interger. YOu can see as below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class InputText {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int i = 0;
    File file;
    file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner read = new Scanner(file);

    while (read.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = read.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(",");
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.lenght; i++) {
            String numStr = numbers[i];
             String x=numStr.replaceAll("\\s+",""); //eleminate the space in any.
            Double num = Double.valueOf(x);
            System.out.println(" num is: " + num); //Here you can store the number in array.
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you split the line `12,242 323,2324` by the comma, then you'll get `12`, `242 323` and `2324`. I wonder which kind of number `242 323` is. Are you sure, that you should split using comma? ;)

Comment: Yeah @Tom right. Sorry for that ignorance. In solution, i made the changes. If you agree. Remove your downvoting.

Comment: If haven't voted on your answer yet. I don't think that you should remove any whitespace in these numbers. More like these numbers are separated by them and the comma is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like that(add also try catch statement)

```
    String line = "";
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    int i=0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // use comma as separator
        String[] lineArray= line.split(",");
        for(int j=0;j<lineArray.length;j++){
           my2DArray[i][j] = lineArray[j];
        }
        i++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<my2DArray[0].length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<my2DArray[1].length;j++){
            System.out.print(my2DArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
     }
```